# Highcharts scatter chart with a name per point for one series

Tags: json, plot, highcharts, scatter

I have this 
`[[26.4,77.5,"US009"],[8.3,6.6,"US013"],[5.8,6.1,"US015"],[4.1,5.1,"US020"],[19,20.6,"US021"],[14.4,26.5,"US022"]]`

use highcharts scatter,
one series serie:

```
{
    data: [[26.4,77.5,"US009"],[8.3,6.6,"US013"],[5.8,6.1,"US015"],[4.1,5.1,"US020"],[19,20.6,"US021"],[14.4,26.5,"US022"]],
    name: 'Source'
}
```

series:

```
[{
                    name: 'Source',
                    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                    data:  [[26.4,77.5,"US009"],[8.3,6.6,"US013"],[5.8,6.1,"US015"],[4.1,5.1,"US020"],[19,20.6,"US021"],[14.4,26.5,"US022"],
[0.2,0,"US024"],[2.2,0.8,"US025"],[13.2,15.9,"US032"],[4.7,0.6,"US034"],[3.5,3.1,"US039"],[0.3,0,"US042"]]
                }]
```

....
i need to give each point plot in my graph a name like "US009" how can i do it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5f3f4nfe/

Comment: Instead of arrays: `[26.4,77.5,"US009"]` use objects: `{x: 26.4, y: 77.5, name: "US009"}`

Comment: oki but how i can use that because in series data i must have [[26.4,77.5],[26.4,77.5]]....

Comment: it is oki i resolved that i use that in tooltip this.point.series.userOptions.data[this.point.index][2]

Comment: @chall How did you get the names e.g. "US009" to show up as a datalabel? I would like the names for each point to show up as a datalabel as well as in the tooltip header if possible. Should I put the `name` as the third item in each array as you did above? Then how do you carry that over to either/both datalabel and tooltip header? Thank you! Also using scatter with lots of points and have a name for each point, but using multiple series. Everything looks great except no name in datalabel and in tooltip header.